# Assigning to sys.excepthook doesn't work: handling uncaught exceptions in mod_wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I want to generate an html page with http response status '200 OK' in case of an uncaught exception in my wsgi application, instead of web server's standard '500 Internal Server Error' response for such case. To test this functionality, I've made the following sample code:

```
import sys

def application(environ, start_response):
    def exception(etype, evalue, trace):
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
        return ['Error']

    sys.excepthook = exception

    1/0

    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['OK']
```

But the function 'exception' is never called, and a standard '500 Internal Server Error' response is still generated by server in case of an uncaught exception.

Is it possible to make a hook for uncaught by try...except exceptions under mod_wsgi somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I've just realized, that a bypass is possible to achieve the goal I need without redefining sys.excepthook:

```
def actual_application(environ, start_response):
    # Real WSGI application goes here
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['OK']

def error(environ, start_response):
    # Format a trace and a debug info to send it to a browser here
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['Error']

def application(environ, start_response):
    # And the mod_wsgi application hook should consist of the only try...except block
    try:
        return actual_application(environ, start_response)
    except:
        return error(environ, start_response)
```